# HTML element appears undefined inside ajax function

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have an html that contains this:

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="welcomeMessage">
    <i class="oi oi-person"></i> 
    Welcome, 
    <i class="oi oi-chevron-bottom"></i>
    <span id="not_var"><i id="not_env"></i></span>
</a>
```

And a jQuery code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var username;
function getUserName(whenDone) {
    $.ajax( {
        url : '../scripts/getUser.php', type : 'get', data : {
        }
        , success : function (response) {
            whenDone(response);
        }
    }
    );
}

//When our ajax function finishes searching for the username, let's add it to the variable
function onComplete(response) {
    username = response;
    $('#welcomeMessage').append(username);
}
//Get the username
getUserName(onComplete);
});
```

Inside the function **onComplete**, the element **$('#welcomeMessage')** is undefined. It is also undefined inside the **success** of the ajax call. And if I try to set said element's HTML after **getUserName(onComplete);** it results that the variable '**username**' is undefined.

What I want is to be able to edit the HTML element with ID "welcomeMessage" with the content of the variable "username" once ajax is done. I used callbacks, but it looks like everything dissappears inside both: the success function and the callback one. As if those functions execute themselves isolated from the HTML and even the other content inside the **$(document).ready** block.

Is there anyway to append to the **$('#welcomeMessage')** the value of '**username**' once the ajax is done fetching the data? That is, by making it available inside the function **onComplete**?

Comment: the element should exist on `success` of the `.ajax` call...this is where you would do what you speak of...I'd recommend looking into the MVVM pattern with KnockoutJS as binding elements to values is much much simpler.

Comment: Hmmmmm. Now that you told me that I double check and it is still undefined. However, that jQuery code is in an external .js file. I tried moving the code of that file to the HTML page and now it works. As you said, the element appears inside the success function. Would you happen to know or have an idea of why it doesn't work when linking an external file while it works when embeeded in the same HTML?

Comment: I would need more information, the best would be posting this on plunkr or jsfiddle...this will allow me to assist you with the correct answer.  As if you are using `include` just make sure you are including the javascript in the `head` or at the end of your `body` tag

Comment: Ah, never mind. I tried it by linking the external js file, but I removed $(document).ready(function(){}); That is, it is the same jQuery posted above, but the ready function is not there. Now it works even if I link it in the HTML. I am guessing that because I already had a $(document).ready(function(){}); embeeded in the HTML, linking an external file with another ready function makes the code in the js file execute separately from the HTML. Although I have no solid proof it works like that. Thank you very much for your help. :)

Comment: You better use `.done() & .always()` instead of `.success() & .complete`.